# How to stop rails_admin from matching all routes beginning with 'admin'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-admin

My rails 4.2 app have routes.rb file like this

```
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'

get '/:id' => 'users#show', as: 'profile'
```

The problem I am now facing is I can have a route that can be

```
example.com/admin
example.com/adminlogs
example.com/adminlinks
example.com/admin-john
```

and so on, and is all redirected to admin.

I need to stop rails_admin from matching every routes that begins with 'admin' but allow /admin to be redirected to rails_admin?

Answer (score 0):

That's how RailsAdmin routes are supposed to behave. But if you have some specific routes you want to match, you can put them before the RailsAdmin line. i.e:

```
get '/adminlogs', to: 'some_controller#some_action'
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
get '/:id' => 'users#show', as: 'profile'
```

Comment: Thanks nick, but the list can be endless (as the app grows), and hence I cannot add them all before rails_admin mount.

Comment: Can't you control what kind of urls get created? For instance, use a regex to check if they start with 'admin' and then not allow that to save.

Comment: I was keeping that for final resort.

Comment: Why do rails admin have to use up every routes that starts with the word 'admin'?
Can you point me to any documentation as to why it behaves like this?

Comment: Just look at the routing section of their github wiki. Why is checking user created urls your last resort? No, in your situation, this is very much preferable to altering the rails admin gem.